# How we can read first element of key from List?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python. How can I get the first value from list? When I am printing x[0] I am getting EmpId:244.

```
txt = "EmpId:244|Name:'Adi'|contact_no:1234567890|product_code:538365085|date:2020-04-06|fileName:Report_BGDE_16-Apr-2020|code:ABC|resubmitted:Y|file_format:CSV"

x = txt.split("|")

print(x[0])
```

I need to return only `EmpId`. Any solution will help me. Thanks

Comment: split again at `:`

Answer (score 3):

You need to split once more on `:` char.

```
txt = "EmpId:244|Name:'Adi'|contact_no:1234567890|product_code:538365085|date:2020-04-06|fileName:Report_BGDE_16-Apr-2020|code:ABC|resubmitted:Y|file_format:CSV"

object = txt.split("|")[0]

key_value =  object.split(':')

key = key_value[0] # EmpId
value = key_value[1] #244
```

Comment: You can iterate each returned item from `txt.split("|")`, instead of selecting only the first element (index `[0]`). Then `product_code` will be accessible from `value`

Answer (score 3):

You could use

```
txt = "EmpId:244|Name:'Adi'|contact_no:1234567890|product_code:538365085|date:2020-04-06|fileName:Report_BGDE_16-Apr-2020|code:ABC|resubmitted:Y|file_format:CSV"

values = (item.split(":") for item in txt.split("|"))
key, value = next(values)
print(value)
```

Comment: Love to see pythonic solutions

Comment: @ConstantinTeo: Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert to dict:

```
my_dict = {k : v for k, v in [item.split(':') for item in txt.split('|')]} 
print(my_dict['EmpId'])
'244'
```

Comment: I think this is the closest solution to what OP is asking.

Comment: I am getting error when I am printing.      print('job id : ',my_dict['EmpId']
KeyError: 'EmpId

Answer (score 2):

This could also neatly help in case you want more fields other than `EmpId` later:

```
dict(item.split(":") for item in txt.split("|"))
```

Answer (score 1):

On extending Mr. @Jan answer, it is much more easy to store the data into a dictionary than a list or tuple or generator

`d = {item.split(":")[0]:item.split(":")[1] for item in txt.split("|")}`

Then, any required field can be retrieved using the key as in

`d['EmpId']` will give 244

`d['product_code']` gives 538365085

Comment: I am getting error when I am printing.      print('job id : ',my_dict['EmpId']
KeyError: 'EmpId